# errors just on iPad 1

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm having a problem just in iPad 1 and iPad 2. iPad 3 is working good, same as other devices with the same size.

This picture is from an iPad3 and it is displaying like it should:

[image: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2v/xI/1P7TuhAN/untitled.png]

Thsi picture is from an iPad2 and an iPad1:

[image]

The width sizes of all those devices are same.

**Does anyone know where the problem is?**

Comment: Your question is confusing and needs more detail. Are these screenshots of a Mobile Web site and/or Mobile Safari?  Is this a problem with a CSS style sheet or is this a native Objective-C app?

Comment: These aren't "errors". They appear to be layout issues.

Comment: Show some code and state exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Those are screenshots of mobile web site. I have made responsive layout and it works good, only on iPad1 and 2 it doesn't. Here is also a web page http://www2.neodata.com/ppai/demo/

Comment: Can you just take a look at http://www.dodaj.rs/f/30/cp/1ck844dL/2014-04-23-10-11-05.png and http://www2.neodata.com/ppai/demo/ when you resize it to iPad width? Why is that menu displaying different?

Answer (score 0):

iPad 1 and iPad 2 has screen resolution lower than iPad 3 which has retinal display, please share the CSS  or use this example:

```
#div-1 img {
    width:375px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    #div-1 img {width:375px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    #div-1 img {width:428px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    #div-1 img {width:434px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    #div-1 img {width:540px;}
}
```

Follow this link to get the screen resolution for different iPads/iPhones
http://www.iosres.com

Comment: Yes, iPad 3+ has a display that is 4x bigger than iPad 2-, however, using the OP's demo page, if I set my browser width to 768px, the issue is not there.

Comment: You have @media listed in the CSS file 49 times, so you have 49 possibility to check, If I were you I would minimise this in the cSS file to 3 or 4 at max.

Comment: Thanks, I will try changing those media queries